# How do you make an Oracle SQL query to

Tags: sql, oracle

This table is rather backwards from a normal schema, and I'm not sure how to get the data I need from it.

Here is some sample data,

```
Value (column)          Info (column)
---------------------------------------------
Supplier_1              'Some supplier'
Supplier_1_email        'foo@gmail.com'
Supplier_1_rating       '5'
Supplier_1_status       'Active'
Supplier_2              'Some other supplier'
Supplier_2_email        'bar@gmail.com'
Supplier_2_rating       '4'
Supplier_2_status       'Active'
Supplier_3              'Yet another supplier'
```

...

I need a query to find the email of the supplier which has the highest rating and is currently of status 'Active'.

Comment: You might want to create a intermediary "Supplier" view to help yourself and others query this table in the future.

Comment: Dear gods, someone has taken EAV and made it **worse**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    m.sup_email, r.sup_rating 
from 
    (select substr(value, 1, length(value) - length('_email') as sup_name, info as sup_email from table where value like '%_email') as m 
left join 
    (select substr(value, 1, length(value) - length('_rating') as sup_name), info as sub_rating from table where value like '%_rating') as r on m.sup_name = r.sup_name 
order by 
   sup_rating desc 
limit 
    1;
```

Comment: Yikes, that's what I was trying to figure out... You're missing the 'Active' criterion, though...

Comment: Wow.  I was in the middle of typing up an ugly hack of an answer when you posted this, and this changed my mind.  Do you intend for "value" to be replaced with a supplier name, or is Oracle smart enough to populate this internally as a buffer variable while calculating the join?

Comment: @OMG Ponies:  As opposed to your approach of counting the number of suppliers first, and then cut-n-pasting a new UNION block to the query for each and every one?  Haha... at least this query is more efficient than simply browsing the database by hand, rather than less so!  :)

Answer (score 1):

For a single pass solution, try:

```
select "email" from 
(select 
    substr("value", 1, 8 + instr(substr("value", 10, length("value")-9),'_')) "supplier", 
    max(case when "value" like '%_status' then "info" end) as "status",
    max(case when "value" like '%_rating' then cast("info" as integer) end) as "rating",
    max(case when "value" like '%_email' then "info" end) as "email"
from "table" t
where "value" like '%_rating' or "value" like '%_email' or "value" like '%_status'
group by substr("value", 1, 8 + instr(substr("value", 10, length("value")-9),'_'))
having max(case when "value" like '%_status' then "info" end) = 'Active'
order by 3 desc
) where rownum = 1
```

(Column names are all double-quoted as some are reserved words.)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Mike's excellent suggestion:

```
CREATE VIEW supplier_names AS
  SELECT SUBSTR(Value,INSTR(Value,'_')+1) AS supplier_id
        ,Info AS supplier_name
  FROM   the_table
  WHERE  INSTR(Value,'_',1,2) = 0;

CREATE VIEW supplier_emails AS
  SELECT SUBSTR(Value,INSTR(Value,'_')+1,INSTR(Value,'_',1,2)-INSTR(Value,'_')-1)
         AS supplier_id
        ,Info AS supplier_email
  FROM   the_table
  WHERE  Value LIKE '%email';

CREATE VIEW supplier_ratings AS
  SELECT SUBSTR(Value,INSTR(Value,'_')+1,INSTR(Value,'_',1,2)-INSTR(Value,'_')-1)
         AS supplier_id
        ,Info AS supplier_rating
  FROM   the_table
  WHERE  Value LIKE '%rating';

CREATE VIEW supplier_statuses AS
  SELECT SUBSTR(Value,INSTR(Value,'_')+1,INSTR(Value,'_',1,2)-INSTR(Value,'_')-1)
         AS supplier_id
        ,Info AS supplier_rating
  FROM   the_table
  WHERE  Value LIKE '%status';
```

The queries will perform like dogs, so I'd suggest you look into creating some virtual columns, or at least function-based indexes, to optimise these queries.